# How do you read a word in from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, input

So I was feeling bored and decided I wanted to make a hangman game.  I did an assignment like this back in high school when I first took C++.  But this was before I even too geometry, so unfortunately I didn't do well in any way shape or form in it, and after the semester I trashed everything in a fit of rage.

I'm looking to make a txt document and just throw in a whole bunch of words
(ie:
test
love
hungery
flummuxed
discombobulated
pie
awkward
you
get
the
idea
)

So here's my question:
How do I get C++ to read a random word from the document?

I have a feeling `#include<ctime>` will be needed, as well as `srand(time(0));` to get some kind of pseudorandom choice...but I haven't the foggiest on how to have a random word taken from a file...any suggestions?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a rough sketch, assuming that the words are separated by whitespaces (space, tab, newline, etc):

```
vector<string> words;
ifstream in("words.txt");
while(in) {
  string word;
  in >> word;
  words.push_back(word);
}

string r=words[rand()%words.size()];
```

Comment: Be sure to #include <fstream>.

Comment: Understood...so 'in' does the same as 'infile'? Or are those two different things?

Comment: And simply out of curiosity and the fact I've not seen it before, what is the push_back() doing? Afraid I've not seen that command before

Comment: It inserts the value to the end of the vector. There's also a push_front.

Comment: The push_back member function of std::vector adds an element (in this case a string) to the end of the vector.

Comment: See the following vector<> reference.  This is the sugary C++ way of doing things.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Comment: "in" here is nothing more than a name for a variable that TrayMan decided to use.  He could've used 'foo', 'bar', 'cheese', or even 'stackoverflow_input_argument'.

Answer (score 1):

The operator >> used on a string will read 1 (white) space separated word from a stream.

So the question is do you want to read the file each time you pick a word or do you want to load the file into memory and then pick up the word from a memory structure. Without more information I can only guess.

Pick a Word from a file:

```
// Note a an ifstream is also an istream. 
std::string pickWordFromAStream(std::istream& s,std::size_t pos)
{
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> iter(s);
    for(;pos;--pos)
    {    ++iter;
    }

    // This code assumes that pos is smaller or equal to
    // the number of words in the file
    return *iter;
}
```

Load a file into memory:

```
void loadStreamIntoVector(std::istream& s,std::vector<std::string> words)
{
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(s),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(words)
             );
}
```

Generating a random number should be easy enough. Assuming you only want psudo-random.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a plain text file (.txt) in Notepad and using the standard C file APIs ([fopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen.html), and [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread.html)) to read from it.  You can use [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets.html) to read each line one at a time.

Once you have your plain text file, just read each line into an array and then randomly choose an entry in the array using the method you've suggested above.

Comment: didn't mean it to seem like I wanted to use word, .txt was the intent.
I tried to place a new line between each of those examples but it seemed to not work.  Could you please explain what you mean? I looked at those two links but I didn't quite understand them.

Comment: You may find the iostream example posted by TrayMan easier to use than the C APIs.  I don't think I can explain it in this little box.

Comment: Beware that Notepad does not neccessarily save in ASCII format.