# How to construct a parser for an input file

Tags: c++, parsing, input

can i please get some guidance to constructing a parser for an input file, I've been looking for a help for weeks, the assignment is already past due, I would just like to know how to do it.

The commented code is what I've tried, but i have a feeling it is more serious than that.  I have a text file and I want to parse it to count the number of times that words appear in the document.

```
   Parser::Parser(string filename) {
   //ifstream.open(filename);

  // source (filename, fstream::in | fstream::out);

 }
```

Comment: **The Dragon Book**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

Comment: You'll probably need to tell us about the format of the input file before we can give any really intelligent advice.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: I think a book about C++ would be more appropriate.

Comment: Are you having trouble parsing the string or reading the text file in?  This will change the kinds of answers you receive.

Comment: all the words in the text file are in lower case, it is a a speech so many words, pauses and such

Comment: @nightcracker, I think at this point any book would be appropriate, as in "get off the internet and study for a change" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a word:

```
std::ifstream  file("FileName");

std::string word;
file >> word; // reads one word from a file.


// Testing a word:
if (word == "Floccinaucinihilipilification")
{
     ++count;
}

// Count multiple words
std::map<std::string, int>   count;

// read a word
++count[word];

// To read many words from a file:

std::string word;
while(file >> word)
{
     // You have now read a word from a file
}
```

Note: That is a real word :-)
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/floccinaucinihilipilification

Comment: so how do i make the parser read the whole file instead of just one word?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625247/how-do-you-read-a-word-in-from-a-file-in-c for reading the whole file.

Comment: I just followed that link. The accepted answer is wrong. Update my answer.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: No. My friends and I have an on going bet (since university) to see who can use the word in everyday conversation (without forcing it).

Answer (score 1):

> The commented code is what I've tried, but i have a feeling it is more serious than that.

I have a feeling you haven't tried a thing. So I am going to do the same.

[Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1440&bih=764&q=count+words+in+file+c%2B%2B&btnG=Google+zoeken&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=count+words+in+file+c%2B%2B&fp=3da6546436c78d85).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers in [How do you read a word in from a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625247/how-do-you-read-a-word-in-from-a-file-in-c) . The easiest way is to use an `ifstream` and `operator>>` to read single words. You can then use a standard container like `vector` (as mentioned in the link above) or `map<string, int>` to remember the actual count.