# read file in C++

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to read a list of words from a file in C++. However, the last word is read twice. I cannot understand why it is so. Can someone help me out?

```
int main () {

ifstream fin, finn;
vector<string> vin;
vector<string> typo;
string word;
fin.open("F:\\coursework\\pz\\gattaca\\breathanalyzer\\file.in");
if (!fin.is_open())
    cout<<"Not open\n";
while (fin) {
    fin >> word;
    cout<<word<<endl;
    vin.push_back(word);
}
fin.close();
}
```

Comment: Accept == click right mark under the best answer (after 20 mins you asked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
while((fin >> word).good()) {
     vin.push_back(word);
}
```

Because `fin >> word` fails and you don't check it.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop condition is off by one:

```
 while (fin >> word) {
    cout<<word<<endl;
    vin.push_back(word);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not read twice. It's simply the old value, since `fin >> word` fails.
Use

```
while(fin >> word)
{
  ...
}
```

instead.
It tries to read and stops loop if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check these..

[How do you read a word in from a file in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625247/how-do-you-read-a-word-in-from-a-file-in-c)

http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/compsci/docs/read.html

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081216024044AAKidaX